# Simple C# OOP inheritance query

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, inheritance

Given the following classes:

```
interface IShape
{
    void Draw();
}

class Rectangle : IShape
{
    public void Draw() { }
}

class Square : Rectangle
{
    public new void Draw()  { }
}
```

Could someone explain what happens in the second Draw method?

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.Draw();
rect = new Square();
rect.Draw();
```

Off hand, I would say the Draw method of the Square class will be called, but when I entered this into VS2013, the Draw method of the Rectangle class was called.

Comment: Research _overriding_ versus _hiding_. Plenty of material out there.

Comment: This will actually begin a foray into some deep concepts about *how* methods themselves are called and bound. Add Virtual Table to your research.

Comment: This is an open for all procedure question. Let the elegant of codes Battle begin.

Answer (score 4):

In the `Square` class, **the `new` keyword tells the compiler that this is a completely new method that just happens to have the same signature as an inherited method**. Because it is a coincidence, it should not override the inherited method.

In this case, when calling `Draw()` through a `Square` variable, the compiler will choose the new method. If it didn't choose the new method in this case, you'd have no way to call it at all, if you think about it. If you want to call the old `Draw()`, you can still call it through a `Rectangle` variable (even on the same instance).

**This is called [hiding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)** and you can do it on any method. You won't need it often - and if possible, you should avoid it, because while its semantics are well-defined, it makes your source code a little bit confusing.

---

On the contrary, if you want **to denote that this is *not* a coincidence and that your intentionally overrides the inherited method with the same signature, you should use the keyword `override`** on your new method. In this case, when calling `Draw()` on an object, you will always get the `Draw()` version of the class you used to create that object (`new Square()`, `new Rectangle()`, etc) no matter what variable you call it from.

Keep in mind that **the method being overridden has to allow itself to be overridden** first. For that to happen, it has to be marked as `virtual` first - methods that aren't marked as `virtual` can't be overridden.

**This is called [overriding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx)**, as the keyword says. You will see and use this one often, because **it enables [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)**, which is one of the core concepts of object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 2):

If the `Draw` method was virtual, then the actual type of the object would be used to determine which method to call, i.e. the `Square.Draw` method.

As the method is not virtual, it's the type of the reference that determines which method to call, i.e. the `Rectangle.Draw` method.

Answer (score 1):

It will call the `Rectangle` version of `Draw`.

The reason for this is because the variable `rect` is of type `Rectangle` at compile time. Because you've overridden `Square`'s `Draw` method via `new`, the runtime cannot lookup the `Square` version of `Draw` at runtime - this would be a lookup in the Virtual Table or V-Table, which doesn't exist in this case because `Draw` is not `virtual`.

Note that the following will call the `Square` version of `Draw`

```
Square sq = new Square();
sq.Draw();
```

Because `sq` is known to be a `Square` at compile time.

If you were to make `Draw` a `virtual` within `Rectangle`, and change `new` to `override`, the original code would call `Square.Draw`. This is allowed, even though `Draw` is the implementation of an interface method.

It is also possible to make a new Interface Method. Consider the following:

```
internal interface IShape
{
    void Draw();
}

internal class Rectangle : IShape
{
    public void Draw() { }
}

internal class Square : Rectangle, IShape
{
    public new void Draw() { }
}
```

In which case the code

```
IShape rect = new Rectangle();
rect.Draw();
rect = new Square();
rect.Draw();
```

will call the second form.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `new` instead of `override`, the method is not overridden, but hidden.

```
class Animal
{
    public virtual void MakeSound() { Console.WriteLine("Animal called"); } 
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    // Note: You can not use override and new in the same class, on 
    // the same method, with the same parameters.  This is just to 
    // show when "new" takes effect, and when "override" takes effect.
    public override void MakeSound() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Animal's MakeSound called for dog"); 
    } 

    public new void MakeSound()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dog's MakeSound called"); 
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dog dogAsDog = new Dog();
        Animal dogAsAnimal = dogAsDog;

        // prints "Dog's MakeSound called"
        dogAsDog.MakeSound();

        // prints "Animal's MakeSound called for dog"
        dogAsAnimal.MakeSound();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have boxed it as a Rectangle, and your Square class *hides* rather than overrides Rectangle's Draw(), the second call will execute Rectangle's Draw method.